# nspredicate for nstableview searchdisplaycontroller multidimension dict from json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, search, nspredicate

Please help me!

I've an ios project, I download datas from webserver, via json output.
This look it:

```
{"sports":
    [{
       "name":"valamilyen Kft.,",       // for tableview section titles
       "leagues":[{
           "id":"174",
           "ny_szam":"",
           "nev":"Fazekas Bela",       // for tableview label.text
           "titulus":"takarito",       // for tableview detail label.text
           "telefonszam":" ",
           "mobiltelefon":"",
           "email":"bla@bla.hu"
      },
     {
        "name":"valamilyen2 Kft.,",   
       "leagues":[{
           "id":"175",
           "ny_szam":"",
           "nev":"Fazekas Jani",
           "titulus":"cipész",
           "telefonszam":" ",
           "mobiltelefon":"",
           "email":"bla@bla.hu"

     }, {[
         "name":"valamilyen2 Kft.,",      
         "leagues":[{
             "id"....
     ]}
```

I can build correctly my NSTableview with section headers, but I cannot apply the searchdisplay controller, I not accessing the sports['leagues']['name'] blocks.

I try apply make a NEV array, the search controller is works, but the names array index not the same table indexpath.row

my data loaded from web, my datas:

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urll options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
JSONDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
sports = JSONDictionary[@"sports"]; 
leagues = [JSONDictionary objectForKey:@"leagues"];
```

my tableview delegate:

```
NSDictionary *sport_1 = sports[indexPath.section];

// get the sport's leagues array
NSArray *leaguesForSport = sport_1[@"leagues"];
    // get the league for this row
NSDictionary *league = leaguesForSport[indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"selected row: %@", league);
...
// and print tablerow
cell.textLabel.text = league[@"nev"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = league[@"titulus"];
```

// and did select row: (it works!)

```
appmain.nev_text = [league objectForKey:@"nev"]; ...
```

I try apply in the

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
```

many many tipy what I found on forums, but I cannot filter the multidimension array for tableview searchDisplayController

I tried:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY leagues.nev like %@)", searchText];
     //self.searchResults = [sports filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

and

```
sports = [sports filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [evaluatedObject[@"nev"] isEqualToString:searchText];
    }]];
```

and

```
[self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
    for (NSArray *jsonArr in leagues)
    {
        NSArray *filterArr=[jsonArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                            [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                             @"SELF.name contains[c] %@",searchText]];//ANY leagues like %@ //@"SELF CONTAINS[CD] %@"
        [self.searchResults addObject:filterArr];
    }
```

and

```
NSMutableArray* filteredResults= [NSMutableArray new]; // This will store the filtered items
    // Here you should have already initialised it
    for( NSDictionary* dict in sports)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary* mutableDict=[dict mutableCopy];
        NSArray* docs= dict[@"leagues"];
        NSPredicate* predicate= [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"nev contains[c] '%@'", searchText];
        docs= [docs filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
        [mutableDict setObject: docs forKey: @"leagues"];
        [filteredResults addObject: mutableDict];
    }
    NSLog(@"filteredResults %@",filteredResults);
```

Please help me any solutions!
Thanks!

Sorry for my poor english!

Comment: I read 5 times your questions, and I still don't know what you want exactly. You're doing "research" on different properties, I don't understand what is not working. You tagged with iOS, but talk about `NSTableView` (OS X). Did you try a `reloadData`?